# Calling a Method Multiple Times (C++)

Tags: methods

so, i have a main method

```c++
int main () {
 int x = 0;
 inc(x);
 inc(x);
 inc(x);
 std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

I'm trying to get my output to be '3' but can't figure out why everytime inc(x) is called x resets to 0.

my inc method:

```c++
int inc(int x){
    ++x;
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    return x;
}
```

my output:

```html
    x = 1
    x = 1
    x = 1
    0
```

Why does x reset after every call to inc(x) and how can i fix this without editing my main function

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
inc(x);
```

I think you need

```
x = inc(x);
```

You may slap your head now.

Comment: That requires that he change main() - his question specifies that he not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing "x" to inc() by value, so changes made in inc() won't be visible in main().

Answer (score 0):

If you want x to be changed you need to pass it by reference and not as a value. Also inc() would need to return void for that to make sense. here is an example.

```
// adding & before x passes the reference to x
void inc(int &x){
    ++x;
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl; 
}
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    inc(x);
    inc(x);
    inc(x);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

this prints

```
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
3
```